# When i'm using Lock in c# why i get: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Tags: c#

I modifying the enumerated collection but, i put Lock around it...
and it don't understan why i get 
"Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."
i don't want to solve it with: "foreach (IObserver obs in _observers.ToList())"

the code is Observer pattern:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Subject sub = new Subject();
        Obs1 obs1 = new Obs1(sub);
        Obs2 obs2 = new Obs2(sub);

        sub.Nodefiy();
        sub.Nodefiy();
        sub.Nodefiy();
        sub.Nodefiy();
        sub.Nodefiy();
        sub.Nodefiy();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IObserver
{
    void Update(int data);
}

public interface ISubscrib
{
    void Reg(IObserver obs);
    void UnReg(IObserver obs);
    void Nodefiy();
}

public class Subject : ISubscrib
{
    private static Object _lock;
    private List<IObserver> _observers;
    private int data = 0;

    public Subject()
    {
        _lock = new Object();
        _observers = new List<IObserver>();
    }

    public void Reg(IObserver obs)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _observers.Add(obs);
        }
    }

    public void UnReg(IObserver obs)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            int ind = _observers.IndexOf(obs);
            if (ind >= 0)
            {
                _observers.RemoveAt(ind);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Nodefiy()
    {
        data = data + 1;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            int sentData = data;
            //foreach (IObserver obs in _observers.ToList<IObserver>())
            foreach (IObserver obs in _observers)
            {
                obs.Update(sentData);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Obs1 : IObserver
{
    private ISubscrib _subj;
    public Obs1(ISubscrib subj)
    {
        _subj = subj;
        _subj.Reg(this);
    }

    public void Update(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Obs1: {0}", data);
    }
}

public class Obs2 : IObserver
{
    private ISubscrib _subj;

    public Obs2(ISubscrib subj)
    {
        _subj = subj;
        _subj.Reg(this);
    }

    public void Update(int data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Obs2: {0}", data);
        if (data > 3)
        {
            _subj.UnReg(this);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone help me?
thanks...

Answer (score 2):

When your Obj2 is invoking Update inside this foreach loop, it is going back to your Subject object and modifying this _observers collection, in the same thread.  That's why the lock is not working.  This is not a synchronization issue.  Your problem is happening in the same thread.

I am not sure what you are trying to do in this code, so I can't help further.

Comment: Just learning, the question now, is how to lock 2 blocks of code to access at the same time?

Comment: A simple answer is using the lock.  That will ensure only 1 thread can get into the critical section.  But this answer is not relevant to your code because your error has nothing to do with threading.

To avoid your error, you just have to make sure you are not modifying the collection inside a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

A lock has to do with thread synchronization, I'm not sure why you thought that would help you.

You can't enumerate over a collection while you are in the middle of modifying that collection (see all the related questions). Change your foreach to this instead:

```
for (int i = _observers.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        _observers[i].Update(sentData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is i think... that while you are iterating the list of _observers you also Add or modify the collection from another thread.

You can sinchronize threads, and you should, because if you try to access an observer that was removed that not even a solution like using a for with an indexer will not help.

Try looking into [Mutexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) to implement a way that while a thread is iterating through the collection another thread will wait until its done before modifying the collection.

Comment: I tried yo replace all the lock with Mutex, same error: public void UnReg(IObserver obs)
        {
            _mut.WaitOne();
            int ind = _observers.IndexOf(obs);
            if (ind >= 0)
            {
                _observers.RemoveAt(ind);
            }
            _mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }